# JPanels in Jframe not shown

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I am making a simple layout for a calculator, actually i am new to java and learning the basics. My problem is that when i run this code, only a JFrame opens and the other panels n its buttons are not shown. PLz help , where my i going wrong.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class Layouts extends JFrame{
        public Layouts(){
            super("Calculator");
            setLookAndFeel();
            setSize(350,350);

            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            BorderLayout border = new BorderLayout();
            setLayout(border);

            GridLayout numbers = new GridLayout(2,2);
            row2.setLayout(numbers);
            row2.add(one);
            row2.add(two);
            row2.add(three);
            row2.add(four);

            GridLayout operators = new GridLayout(2,2);
            row3.setLayout(operators);
            row3.add(plus);
            row3.add(subtract);
            row3.add(multiply);
            row3.add(equals);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        private void setLookAndFeel()
        {
            try
            {
            IManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.lang.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
            }
            catch(Exception exc)
            {
            }
        }

        //row 1
        JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
        JTextField text = new JTextField(20);

        //row 2
        JPanel row2 = new JPanel();
        JButton one = new JButton("1");
        JButton two = new JButton("2");
        JButton three = new JButton("3");
        JButton four = new JButton("4");

        //row3
        JPanel row3 = new JPanel();
        JButton plus = new JButton("+");
        JButton subtract = new JButton("-");
        JButton multiply = new JButton("*");
        JButton equals = new JButton("=");

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        Layouts l1 = new Layouts();
        }

   }
```

Comment: i can't see where you are adding row2 and row3 to your jframe.

Comment: Avoid extending top level containers if possible. Much easier, in the long run, to extend a JPanel and create your UI on it. This makes it more flexible and reusable as you can add the panel to what ever container you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to add all of the components (i.e row2, row3 etc..)

Example:

```
add(row2,BorderLayout.CENTER)
add(row3,BorderLayout.SOUTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BorderLayout border = new BorderLayout();
setLayout(border);
```

But you aren't adding anything to `border` ! Add the `numbers` and `operators`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `JPanel`s and `JButton`s to `JFrame`. The `JFrame` in this case is your `Layouts` class. So do something like :

```
row1.add(text);
this.add(row1); 

row2.add(one);
row2.add(two);
row2.add(three);
row2.add(four);
this.add(row2); 

...
```

check this tutorial is is a very useful one [JButton, JPanel & JFrame examples](http://www.hcroboting.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3&Itemid=11)